# Why is the members of an inherited interface not available using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

When reflecting on an interface type, I only get the members of the specific type, not inherited members.

In this over-simplified example, the program only prints "Name", not "ItemNumber", "Name" as I would expect:

```
using System;

public interface IBasicItem
{
    string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem : IBasicItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof (IItem);
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
}
```

What is the rationale behind this ? When I am inheriting from the base interface, I am saying that any of the implementations of my interface, must also implement the inherited members. In other words, IItem *is-a* IBasicItem. So why does the inherited member not show up using reflection ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is exactly what Phil Haack just blogged about.

From the ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure specification:

> 8.9.11 Interface type derivation Interface types can require the
>   implementation of one or more other
>   interfaces. Any type that implements
>   support for an interface type shall
>   also implement support for any
>   required interfaces specified by that
>   interface. This is different from
>   object type inheritance in two ways:
>
> - **Object types form a single inheritance tree; interface types do
>     not.**
> - Object type inheritance specifies how implementations are inherited;
>     required interfaces do not, since
>     interfaces do not define
>     implementation. Required interfaces
>     specify additional contracts that an
>     implementing object type shall
>     support.
>
> To highlight the last
>   difference, consider an interface,
>   IFoo, that has a single method. An
>   interface, IBar, which derives from
>   it, is requiring that any object type
>   that supports IBar also support IFoo.
>   It does not say anything about which
>   methods IBar itself will have.

Referenced from:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/10/interface-inheritance-esoterica.aspx

Comment: Doh...I can tell I'm sleepy this morning. +1 for the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

A good way to think about this is that interfaces do not have "inheritance" the same way classes do. Inheritance implies the "is a kind of" relationship, but interface "inheritance" actually implies the "is required to provide this service" relationship.

When we say

```
interface IEnumerator<T> : IDisposable
```

what we're saying is not so much "sequence enumerators are a kind of disposable thing" as "if you provide the enumerator service then you must *also* provide the dispose service".

Does that now make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're working with interfaces. Interfaces don't get the same inheritance structure that classes do.

If you have a class that implements these interfaces, you'll see the proper chain (assuming you use "BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy").

Try creating a class that implements the lower level interface, and you should see what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your not asking for the information you want to know. In other words, as your inherited properties have a different meaning than the properties you get from interfaces, you have to access them differently.

Therefore, you could access through reflection like this:

```
foreach ( var iface in type.GetInterfaces() )
{
  foreach ( var prop in iface.GetProperties() )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( iface.Name +"-"+ prop.Name );
  }
}
```

Since class inheritance is different than interface compliance, it seems logical to access them differently.