# Expression.Call on Expression.PropertyOrField on Interface IList<T> throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, reflection

So if i try and call "Clear" on a property of a class that is of type IList it throws. If i do the same thing on a constant of type IList the program runs fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parent = new Parent(new List<SomeClass>());
        parent.Data.Add(new SomeClass("Test"));
        Console.WriteLine(parent.Data.Count);

        var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(parent.Data), "Clear", null, null), null);
        var x = expr.Compile();
        x.DynamicInvoke();

        Console.WriteLine(parent.Data.Count);

        var expr2 = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(parent), "Data"), "Clear", null, null), null);
        var x2 = expr.Compile();
        x2.DynamicInvoke();

        Console.WriteLine(parent.Data.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public Parent(IList<SomeClass> data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }
        public IList<SomeClass> Data { get; set; }
    }
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass(string value) { }
    }
}

// output:
// 1
// 0
// Exception of type: InvalidOperationException was thrown
```

Is this just a bug or is there some logical reason it does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behave like that because of how "inheritance" in interfaces works in .net. Imagine that you have interfaces like that:

```
public interface ITest 
{
    string Property{get;set;}
}


public interface ISubTest : ITest
{

}
```

Then call this :

```
typeof(ITest).GetProperty("Property"); // returns property
typeof(ISubTest).GetProperty("Property"); // returns null
```

So in your case casting to ICollection would work cause Clear method is defined in ICollection interface not on IList interface.

More about interface type derivation in the answer for [Why is the members of an inherited interface not available using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783379/why-is-the-members-of-an-inherited-interface-not-available-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

I'll mark whoever responds with an existing connect bug or has some reasonable explanation for this behavior as the answer but... the solution is to cast to ICollection before making the call

```
        var expr2 = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(parent), "Data"), typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(parent.Data.GetType().GetGenericArguments()))
            , "Clear", null, null), null);
```